# Load page at specific point with jQuery (without animation!)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hash, scroll

I want to load a page at a specific `div` on my page without animating to that point. Below is the code I'm using right now which animates to said `div`. I haven't been able to figure out how to do this same function without animation.

**jQuery:**

```
if(window.location.hash) {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    var link = $("[href='"+ hash +"']");
    if ( hash == "#specific-url" ) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#specific-div").offset().top
        }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way set `animate` time `0`ms

```
if(window.location.hash) {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    var link = $("[href='"+ hash +"']");
    if ( hash == "#specific-url" ) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#specific-div").offset().top
        }, 0);
}
```

---

You can use

[.scrollTop()](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

```
$(document).scrollTop($("#specific-div").offset().top);
```

---

[.scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollIntoView)

```
$("#specific-div")[0].scrollIntoView(true);
```

or

```
document.getElementById(specific-div).scrollIntoView(true);
```

Answer (score 3):

instead of this:

```
 $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#specific-div").offset().top
    }, 1000);
```

do this:

```
$(document).scrollTop($("#specific-div").offset().top);
```

---

In you code you were trying to animate the `html,body` of your document, so as you want to move at a specific location in your document i think you can directly set the `.scrollTop()` of your document the way i suggested to you above.